# Android - Make view scolling like parallax with BottomSheetBehaviour

Tags: android, parallax, bottom-sheet

I have two views: ImageView as a background and LinearLayout (with BottomSheetBehaviour). I want to make ImageView scrolling with parallax effect (don't use CollaspingToolbarLayout).

```
bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            }

            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSlide()... slideOffset = $slideOffset")
            }
        })
```

With `slideOffset`, can we make parallax effect for other view?

My full xml code [at here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/gKlwA09v)

I want when `bottomSheet` sliding, `lytHeaderBackgroundAndMap` has effect like parallax.

Plese help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your other code.

Comment: Yes, I updated my question. You can see full code.